# Sharing bookmarks on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, browser-addons, bookmarks, xmarks

I'm a Xmarks user. I'm sharing bookmarks between Chrome and Firefox and I'm also using Chrome and Firefox on portableapps.

I have lots of problems with Xmarks like lots of empty folders keep on being added, bookmark duplication, and now my bookmarks got deleted for no reason.

Can anyone suggest a good method to share bookmarks with different browsers?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [Google Bookmarks](https://www.google.com/bookmarks/). You can use a Google Bookmarks bookmarklet in Chrome & Firefox to add bookmarks and fetch them in either browser from the Google Bookmarks site.